# Can I get details of users who downloaded my android app?

Tags: android, google-play, userinfo

Is there a way how to get details of users who downloaded my android app from Google Play store? I'd need for example email address, phone number or at least phone id...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

For that you need to write in your code to get the Phone IMIE No, or any specific information you need and then send those to your server and save them in your any specific Activity class when the user first time open your App. This could be done programatically before the app is sent to the play store.

Comment: isn't it possible from play store as well? as a publisher?

Comment: The play store only gives you the details of the Device Names, Geo Locations of the users. But no Details of the User or its Device Private Information.

Comment: Thank you Pravinsingh. Is there a similar option for iOS apps too? (asking as a business analyst, sorry if the answer is obvious)

Comment: @MichalHruška You can get the required information such as active user,how many downloaded etc from Crashlytics/Fabric https://www.crashlytics.com/. Please look into it.